# Transform json using jslt to include space character

Tags: json

How to transform a JSON payload to include a space character before and after colon(:)
The Source Json needs to be transformed to Target Json.
how to do this in JSLT, Please suggest other options as well. Thanks

Source Json

{
  "code":"ABC",
  "description":"XYZ"
}

Target Json

{

"code" : "ABC",
  "description" : "XYZ"

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you mean [the Java JSLT](https://github.com/schibsted/jslt) this isn't something it does. It works on the JSON objects, so from JSLT's point of view the input and the output are the same.

You can probably do what you want to do by loading the JSON, then controlling how it's serialized. This will actually give you spaces on each side of the colon:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();  
System.out.println(mapper.writerWithDefaultPrettyPrinter().writeValueAsString(input));
```

If you need more detailed control you can implement your own [PrettyPrinter](http://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-core/javadoc/2.7/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/PrettyPrinter.html?is-external=true) to set this up however you want.